# sorting of arrays in desc order by values in PHP

Tags: php, sorting

Is there a function sort array by values (not by keys) in desc order? Following is the array which is to be sorted.

```
array(
0 => 3223,
1 => 675,
2 => 56,
3 => 66899,
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`asort()` and `arsort()` will do this.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
<?php
$fruits = array("lemon", "orange", "banana", "apple");
rsort($fruits);
foreach ($fruits as $key => $val) {
    echo "$key = $val\n";
}
?>
```

I hope it will hepls you

and see also http://php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php